# Linq use property name equality

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class structured this way I read in from a user data source:

```
Item
Warehouse
Customer
Forecast_4_2018
Forecast_5_2018
```

And so on - I am doing some calculations with this data and want to dynamically choose which "forecast" property to use by current month.

```
int year, int month
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(CombinedForecast).GetProperties();
PropertyInfo useThisForecast = null;
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if(property.Name.ContainsAll(year.ToString(), month.ToString()))
    {
        useThisForecast = property;                   
    }       
}
```

So in this case `useThisForecast == Forecast_4_2018`

I have a LINQ query to group the data and sum the quantities but I want to speciy the property to sum by the property name.

```
var results = from a in CombinedForecast
    group a by new
    {
        a.ItemNumber,
        a.ShipFromNumber,
        a.ShipToNumber
    } into grouping
    select new SummedOrders
    {
        SummedQuantity = grouping.Sum(x => x.Forecast_4_2018.Value /*x.GetType().Name.Equals(useThisForecast.Name).Value */ ),
        Item = grouping.Key.ItemNumber,
        Warehouse = grouping.Key.ShipFromNumber.ParseInt(),
        CustomerNumber = grouping.Key.ShipToNumber
    };

return results.ToList();
```

In the code below I'm attempting to use the name of the property rather then set it but I can't get the syntax right.

```
 SummedQuantity = grouping.Sum(x => x.Forecast_4_2018.Value /*x.GetType().Name.Equals(useThisForecast.Name).Value */
```

Comment: Is this plain Linq (aka Linq-To-Objects), or is it Linq-To-Something?

Comment: @nvoight this is plain Linq as far as I understand it, I am making a new object out of the result set.

Comment: Surely there is a way to read the data into a collection of `Forecasts` in your object, and avoid this trickiness? It can be done as you have described but is messy and slow.

Comment: @Rhumborl The data source is an excel sheet the company uses that I read into the DB with an SSIS package and EF to produce the model. The data is structured that way from the source.

Comment: Basing the design of your software on someone's Excel skills is not going to make you a happy programmer in the long run. Do what you need to in order to import the data, but import it into a more general data structure where you don't need to pull stuff like this. A year should be a row, not a column. God knows what the spreadsheet will look like next year.

Comment: @JohnWu I agree with you and long term i want to tackle the "spreadsheet madness" that plagues my employer.

Comment: The syntax is `useThisForecast.GetValue(x)`, but it would definitely be better to transform the data into something (more) usable on read and then you just need to modify the reader when spreadsheets change.

Comment: @NetMage that did it, i did have to explicit cast it. i agree on changing the structure. I am one of two developers at my company just not enough time. I have some large excel sheets I'm loading from a division here and massaging with SSIS packages which is why the structure is the way it is. Feel free to leave your comment as an answer if you want credit.

Comment: @Matt Just because I hate questions answered in comments hanging around unclosed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `PropertyInfo.GetValue` method to retrieve the corresponding property value from an object of the proper type:

```
SummedQuantity = grouping.Sum(x => (dynamic)useThisForecast.GetValue(x));
```

Note that `GetValue` returns an `object` which you may need to cast - I cheated and used `dynamic` since I didn't know the type of the properties.

Also if you might be dealing with fields or properties, some extension methods on `MemberInfo` can be helpful:

```
public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}

public static Type GetMemberType(this MemberInfo member) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            return mfi.FieldType;
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            return mpi.PropertyType;
        case EventInfo mei:
            return mei.EventHandlerType;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware I could use the property In that manner but this worked with very little I had to change. Those extension methods are helpful as well so I don't need to access the object by it's "name".